# I am confused in strings

Tags: c, string

I am studying pointers right now. So, arrays are simultaneously studied with that. It says that address of first of element of array `arr` is `&arr[0]` which can also be written as `arr`.

But as i know that string is an array of characters so if have a string:

`char string[] = "ilovejapan";`

and then print it using printf

`printf("%s", string);`

shouldn't it be just printing the first address? Really confused Now.

**Question updated: Now in the example below `*W` points to word that means it pointers to the first address of the string `word` right? How does this access complete string `word`?**

```
int getword(char *word,  int lim) 
{ 
int c, getch(void); 
void ungetch(int); 
char *W  = word; 
while (isspace(c = getch()))
; 
if (c  !=  EOF) 
*W++  = c; 
if (lisalpha(c)) { 
*W  = '\0'; 
return c; 
} 
for (  ;  --lim > 0; W++) 
if ( lisalnum(*W = getch())) { 
  ungetch ( *W) ; 
  break; 
} 
*W  = '\0'; 
return word[O]; 
}
```

Comment: Read sections 6 and 8 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Comment: to add to this -- you can declare a string like this: `char * string = "ilovejapan"`. that creates a string and stores its starting address in a _pointer_ called `string`. the pointer can be used in code as if it were an array (e.g., `string[2]` yields `o`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The conversion specifier `%s` says, "Give me the address of a character. I will print that character, and then look at the next higher address and print *that* character, and so forth, until the character at the address I'm looking at is zero". So `string` is indeed the address of a character, but `printf` knows what to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

`char string[0] = "ilovejapan";` isn't a valid declaration.  Maybe you meant to leave the `0` out?

Anyway, the `%s` format specifier is intended to match up with a pointer to a string, which in your case is just fine.  It prints characters from that address up until the terminating null character.

Comment: If you have a new question, post a new question.  Editing this one isn't likely to attract as much attention.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass `string` in `printf("%s", string);`, you are telling `printf` you want to print a string and you are telling the function the address of the first character in the string. Using its address, `printf` can figure out what character is stored at that address, and increments the address of the first character to get the address of the second character, and prints that character, and so on. It stops printing when it finds a character (not that character's address, but the actual character itself) whose value is `'\0'` (the "zero" character, or the character represented by the number `0`). If that makes any sense.

Comment: The question has always said that 'address of first of element of array `arr` is `&arr[0]` which can also be written as `arr`', so your first sentence is in danger of tilting at windmills.  It's correct, but the question didn't seem to be in doubt about its correctness anyway.